# Can't seem to redirect user on session timeout in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am running laravel 8 and this site has been upgraded since laravel 5.2 I believe.  Currently I have an admin section and when the session times out it goes to /login.  I also have another user section where login is used.  I am looking for a way to control where the user is redirected based on the url.  If they are /admin/* I want to redirect to /admin/login.

My problem is I can not find where this is controlled.  I have tried a variety of ways.  Looking at the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#redirecting-unauthenticated-users) it says I can change the redirectTo function in /App/http/Middleware/Authenticate.php.  Issue is I did not have an Authenticate file.  I created one and copied the Authenticate from the vendor src file and just tried to do a dd() on the construct method but it just skips past it so when checking where to send them it does not seem to use this file.  If I do the same in the vendor folder version it will dump out.

I know I should not edit any code in the vendor folder as it will get overridden with an upgrade so my question is how/where do I edit this redirectTo function.

Comment: You can create a middleware for that

Comment: There is an auth middleware already in place from the standard laravel make:auth back in the earlier version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check the App\Http\Kernal.php and confirm if the $routeMiddleware array has "Authenticate" middleware or not?

**App\Http\Kernal.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // ...

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        // ...
    ]
}
```

and you can update the Authenticate as follow where we can check the request URL.

**App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        // Or we can check the particular segment of the URL.
        if (str_contains($request->url(), 'admin')) {
            return route('admin/login');
        } else {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is it.  My Kernel.php showed it as 'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class.